# Crear un origen de eventlog en instalador de aplicación

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

Yo tengo una aplicación de escritorio creada en 
VS 2015 que ejecuta un ciclo y si algo sucede en ese ciclo necesito enviarlo a un origen en el event log 
¿cómo hago en el instalador para crear ese origen si no existe?

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que tipo de instalador estas usando?

Comment: Y por qué en el instalador y no en la aplicación?

Comment: Porque para crear un origen se ocupan permisos de administración por seguridad y quien ejecuta la aplicación no necesariamente los va a tener siempre... en cambio en el instalador se hace solo una vez y es màs sencillo que sea un administrador quien lo instale.

Comment: Una explicación totalmente razonable. Necesitariamos saber como te dijo @gbianchi que instalador usas. ClickOnce?

Comment: Sí claro, yo utilizo el Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 1):

Desde Windows NT existe el registro de eventos. Tanto aplicaciones como servicios Windows y componentes del sistema operativo pueden utilizar este servicio de registro centralizado ya sea informar de eventos que han tenido lugar tal como un error al iniciar un componente o completar una acción, o simplemente dejar constancia como una bitácora de que algo sucedió.

La API de .NET para escribir eventos en un registro es sencilla y fácil de usar. Solo que, para escribir en el registro de eventos, el programa debe registrar un origen de registro de eventos.
Este registro de un origen de registro de eventos requiere privilegios de administrador, lo cual puede ser un problema en las cuentas de usuario estándar en Windows XP y Vista, ya que estas cuentas no tienen privilegios de administrador.

Por lo anterior el mejor momento para registrar el origen del evento es cuando se instala el programa. Una vez más, .NET proporciona el marco para cooperar con el servicio de Windows Installer, lo que lo hace una tarea relativamente fácil y a prueba de balas.
Primer se debe agregar una clase a su programa decorada con el atributo correcto

Por ejemplo:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;
 
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class InstallEventLog : Installer
{
    public const string EventSource = "Desk Drive";
 
    public InstallEventLog()
    {
        var eventLogInstaller = new EventLogInstaller();
        eventLogInstaller.Source = EventSource;
        Installers.Add(eventLogInstaller);
    }
}
```

Esta clase puede residir en un ensamblado independiente (.dll) o incrustarse en el programa principal.

Los atributos [RunInstaller(true)] especifican si se debe o no invocar el instalador de acciones personalizadas de Visual Studio o la herramienta de instalación (Installutil.exe) cuando se instala el ensamblado.

La clase EventLogInstaller instala y configura un registro de eventos desde el que la aplicación va a leer o escribir al ejecutarse.
Al llamar a la herramienta de instalación (Installutil.exe), observe el RunInstallerAttribute. Si es true, la herramienta instala todos los elementos de la colección Installers que están asociados con el instalador del proyecto.

Luego, se debe agregar una acción personalizada al instalador en sí. Si usa un proyecto de instalación de Visual Studio, haga clic con el botón secundario en el proyecto de instalación, seleccione Ver y Acciones personalizadas. En la página Acciones personalizadas, haga clic con el botón secundario en el nodo "Instalar" y, a continuación, en "Agregar acción personalizada" (customaction)

Seleccione una carpeta y un elemento. Como agregué mi acción de instalador personalizado a mi ejecutable principal, seleccioné "Salida principal". Haga doble clic y se agregará.

(customaction2)

Eso es todo. Al ejecutar el instalador, se registra el origen del evento. Si el origen del evento ya está registrado, no sucede nada. Recomendaría no desinstalar el origen de eventos una vez instalado.

Escribir eventos en el registro es aún más fácil. Por ejemplo

```
public static void LogError(string message)
{
    Log(message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
}
 
public static void LogInformation(string message)
{
    Log(message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
 
static void Log(string message, EventLogEntryType logEntryType)
{
    try
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(InstallEventLog.EventSource, message, logEntryType);
    }
 
    catch
    {
        // in case the event source is not registered
    }
}
```

Se puede agregar a la clase Program.cs que genera el Asistente para proyectos de Visual Studio C#.

Comment: Danilo, muchas gracias por compartir la solución. Lamentablemente, las respuestas que son solo un enlace son consideradas de baja calidad, principalmente porque si en el futuro el enlace deja de estar en linea, la respuesta simplemente carece de sentido. Te invito a que, manteniendo en enlace, adjuntes las partes básicas de lo que está explicado en el enlace a tu respuesta para que sea totalmente completa. Un saludo

Comment: Listo, solo que para efectos de dar créditos a quien lo merece puse el enlace, sin embargo, lo que escribí es prácticamente lo que el enlace indica